# How I can use variables in nginx config to provide some paths for NGINX?

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I want make dynamic subdomains with logs in separate directories, but have a problem with it:

1. If I provide a path to logs like `/var/www/demo/subdomains/$sub/logs/access.log` and same with error, NGINX writes `/var/www/demo/subdomains/$sub/logs/error.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)`
2. If I provide a path like in config now `/var/www/demo/subdomains/logs/$sub-error.log` I have the problem that `$sub-access.log` is named correctly like `demo1-access.log` or `demo2-acces.log`, but `$sub-error.log` is named just as `$sub-error.log`. For 2 domains I have 3 files - `demo1-access.log`, `demo2-access.log`, and `$sub-error.log`.

What do I need to change to make the first method working? The second is fine too, but not so beautiful.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name "~^(?<sub>.+)\.deb\.test$";
    root /var/www/demo/subdomains/$sub/www;
    index index.php index.html;

    access_log /var/www/demo/subdomains/logs/$sub-access.log combined;
    error_log /var/www/demo/subdomains/logs/$sub-error.log info;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FLIENAME $document_root@fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~* /(images|cache|media|logs|tmp)/.*\.(php|pl|py|jsp|asp|sh|cgi)$ {
        return 403;
        error_page 403 /403_error.html;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|pdf|flv)$ {
        expires 1y;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|swf|xml|txt)$ {
        expires 14d;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Adding one more server block with error_log directive works the same:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name "~^(?<sub>.+)\.deb\.test$";
        error_log /var/www/demo/subdomains/logs/$sub-error.log info;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use variables (with some limitations) in the `access_log` directive, but it is not possible to use variables in the `error_log` directive. To log errors to a different file, you would need to use a different `error_log` directive, probably in a new `server` block.

Comment: I have moved error_log directive from first server block to second and it works same.